# How to limit httpPost size in kb's?

Tags: c#, post, http-post

I need to transmit some data in streaming, but the limit is 16kb, above that, the components that will present this data, will give an error

```
//Get from Database
result = repository.GetAll();

//Converting and Posting
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None);
var postToPowerBi = HttpPostAsync(powerBiPostUrl, "[" +jsonString + "]");
```

How to limit the HttpPostAsync to 16kb to prevent error?

Comment: Do you want to skip calling the post if the size is > 16kb or do you want to somehow truncate in a way that won't cause the post to blow up?  The former is fairly easy.  The latter... not so much.

Comment: @stephen.vakil I need to ensure that this file generated in HttpPost Async is smaller than 16kb, regardless of the size of the database query. If it exceeds this size, the transmission is interrupted.